# check terminal if open

Tags: java

I am using Ubuntu right now and I am able to open a terminal through Java code. But my problem is that when I close my program after the terminal has been opened, I will see a message saying that the terminal I opened has been closed?

Here is my code for opening the terminal:

```
String command = "gnome-terminal -x bash cd ~/Desktop";
String cmd[] = { "gnome-terminal", "-x", "bash", "-c", "sudo gedit ~/Desktop/wat.txt" };
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();      
Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Just a question, why are you launching a terminal to then launch gedit from that? Why not just launch gedit?

Comment: Cause its an application. Users are lazy.

Comment: I understand that you want to launch gedit for your (lazy) user, but why launching a terminal, and not just directly gedit? With your current command they will see a terminal popping up, which opens gedit. Just wondering whether you really need that terminal.

Comment: No.. its just and example. Here is another exmple. What if a user want to download through wget. Some newbie in linux like me are scared in terminal. So i want to create a gui.

Comment: Well, if you want to run wget, you do not need a terminal either. If you would execute the command "wget" from your Java app, or "gedit" it will launch, without any terminal. The terminal is mainly meant give a user the possibility to manually launch programs. If you just want to launch programs, you can do that without the terminal. any command you run with the rt.exec(cmd), will be launched as if it was typed in the terminal.

Comment: @W.Goeman i tried it in axel but it shows the terminal.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) on Process. The API says:

> causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated.
>
> returns the exit value of the process. By convention, 0 indicates normal termination.

If you want your programm to continue function, then be sure to call your code in separate Thread.